# Chrome extension run angular after loading sync data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-storage

How can i run angularjs engine after getting data from chrome.storage?

I have this code in `app.js`:

```
'use strict';

var host = '';
var port = '';
chrome.storage.sync.get({
    host: '',
    port: '',
}, function(items) {
    host = items.host;
    port = items.port;
});
// need to run this line after data is retrived from chrome.storage
var app = angular.module('TouchApp', ['TouchApp.services', 'TouchApp.controllers', 'TouchApp.directives']);
```

After chrome gets data, then run angularjs engine.

Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of the callback is to run after the async function is done. So you need to put code there.

```
var app;

chrome.storage.sync.get({
    host: '',
    port: '',
}, function(items) {
    host = items.host;
    port = items.port;
    app = angular.module('TouchApp', ['TouchApp.services', 'TouchApp.controllers', 'TouchApp.directives']);
});
```

Comment: Doesn't work that way: `ncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.5/$injector/modulerr?p0=TouchApp&p1=Error%3…lbnjobokpcdcadjjgleogcnjajcpgdie%2Fassets%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%3A17%3A339)`

Comment: But i don't get this error on my example? I don't know what can be problem?

Comment: Possibly a problem with `use strict`? Have you defined `var app;` outside this?

Comment: Now i defined it, and it works. Thanks. So this way i am sure that it will first get data and set it to this variables then run angular?